# A question on Harmonic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

$f$ and $g$ are two given continuous functions on $\overline {D(0,1)}$) and both $f$, $g:\overline {D(0,1)}\to\Bbb R$ are harmonic on unit disc $D(0,1)$. Now, If $f\equiv g$ on some $C=\{e^{i\theta} :a\lt\theta\lt b\}$ where $a,b \in[0,2\pi]$ and $a\lt b$. Does this information implies that $f\equiv g$ on $\overline {D(0,1)}$? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the identity theorem for harmonic functions isn't that strong.

For every continuous function $h \colon \partial D(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$, there is a unique function $\overline{h}$ that is harmonic in $D(0,1)$ and continuous on $\overline{D(0,1)}$ with boundary values $h$.

So we can choose $h$ vanishing on the arc $\{e^{i\theta} : a \leqslant \theta \leqslant b\}$ but not identically, if $[a,b] \neq [0,2\pi]$, and then $g = f + \overline{h}$ coincides with $f$ on the specified arc, but not everywhere.

If $[a,b] = [0,2\pi]$, then $f$ and $g$ must be identical.

Comment: Fisher Can you give me some example of function which vanishes on that arc?

Comment: For the arc $[0,\pi]$, we could take $h(e^{i\theta}) = 0$ if $0\leqslant \theta \leqslant \pi$, $h(e^{i\theta}) = \sin \theta$ if $\pi < \theta \leqslant 2\pi$. Or one could take $h(e^{i\theta}) = \operatorname{dist}(e^{i\theta}, \{e^{i\psi} : \psi \in [a,b]\})$. The harmonic extension to the closed unit disk would then be given by the Poisson integral. For the first example it might even be possible to get an explicit representation, I don't know; usually, the Poisson integral is as explicit as one gets.